# Color clustered features based on clustered point counts

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin.ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm developing an app using Xamarin.iOS and Mapbox iOS SDK (Naxam.Mapbox.iOS NuGet package [here](https://github.com/NAXAM/mapbox-ios-binding).
And i'm following this example in MapBox iOS SDK website: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/clustering/.

And i'm having problems converting this part of code to C#:

```
// Color clustered features based on clustered point counts.
let stops = [
    20: UIColor.lightGray,
    50: UIColor.orange,
    100: UIColor.red,
    200: UIColor.purple
]
```

And:

```
circlesLayer.circleColor = NSExpression(format: "mgl_step:from:stops:(point_count, %@, %@)", UIColor.lightGray, stops)
```

I'm able to set an unique color to the cluster if i do it like this:

```
circlesLayer.CircleColor = NSExpression.FromConstant(FromObject(UIColor.Green));
```

But i'm not managing to do it if i follow the example, in it, the Expression format takes 3 Parameters: **string**, **UiColor**, **Array**

But in C# `NSExpression.FromConstant`, takes at max 2 params: **string** and a **NSObject[]**, so i created this: (to match the array "stops" in the examle)

```
NSDictionary[] stops = new NSDictionary[]
{
    new NSDictionary(new NSNumber(0), FromObject(UIColor.Green)),
    new NSDictionary(new NSNumber(20), FromObject(UIColor.Blue)),
    new NSDictionary(new NSNumber(100), FromObject(UIColor.Red))
};
```

But it no success, what should i be doing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary[] stops = new NSDictionary[]
{
    new NSDictionary(new NSNumber(0f), FromObject(UIColor.Green)),
    new NSDictionary(new NSNumber(20f), FromObject(UIColor.Blue)),
    new NSDictionary(new NSNumber(100f), FromObject(UIColor.Red))
};
```

Using nsfloat might be the way to go

Answer (score 1):

It should be an nsfloat rather than a integer, so define the first param like this:

```
new NSNumber(0f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSExpression.FromFormat(string format, NSObject [] parameters)` for this purpose.

Something like this:

```
circlesLayer.CircleColor = NSExpression.FromFormat ("mgl_step:from:stops:(point_count, %@, %@)", stops)
```

Where `stops` is what you had above with the dictionary.

Comment: i already tried that, i guess i didn't explained correctly, when i said: "But in C# NSExpression.FromConstant, takes at max 2 params: string and a NSObject[], so i created this: (to match the array "stops" in the examle)", it means i used my NSDictionary in the NSObject[] parameter, and yes, that should be the solutions, but it's not working, thank you for help